# How to protect a server from DoS attacks?

Tags: debian, denial-of-service

I have Debian 7.11 and 4GB of RAM, how i can make a DoS protection for server and for Stress attacks on Apache2?

Today i have recieved one dos attack but the attack it was light

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  To improve your chance of getting answer you expect, read also [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your question might be better asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

make it respond only on intern requests.

Comment: But I need to be accessible to everyone